# Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin 5.2.3 is not compatible with netcoreapp1.1

Tags: .net, asp.net-web-api, .net-core, visual-studio-2017

It's new WebApi project on .NET Core 1.1 on VS2017.

I'm going to install package DryIoc.WebApi.Owin from Nuget, but it requires a lot of dependent stuff under "Net45". One of them is *Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin 5.2.3*.

I had already added line in *.csproj file

```
<PackageTargetFallback Condition="'$(TargetFramework)'=='Net45'">
  $(PackageTargetFallback);portable-net45+win8+wpa81+wp8
</PackageTargetFallback>
```

but it didn't save me.

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install that on .net core 2 + you've to configure Owin pipeline on top of asp.net core + you need visual studio 2017 preview 3

I'm gonna add a sample in 1 day

Comment: I'm not sure about this answer. Need to install .net core2 ... why? I already installed VS2017 release professional....

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find enough time to create a sample. but to make story short: Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Owin is a full .NET framework library and .NET Core 2 supports adding some .NET full based libraries. You can't do that in .NET core 1.1 + you've to configure owin pipeline on top of ASP.net core pipeline, because web API works on owin

Comment: I revealed the relationships between .Net Standart, .Net Core and .Net Framework yesterday. So, for now, your answer is clear for me and I understand right direction for moving ahead. Thank you!

Comment: @rock_walker ASP.NET Web API Owin on top of asp.net core / .net core 2 >> https://github.com/ysmoradi/WebApiAspNetCore I've tested that on top of Linux & windows. But I wasn't able to test that on mac os.